# Selenium with firefox and Mocha does not go to URL

Tags: selenium-webdriver, mocha.js

I believe there is a minor basic issue with this code, but I'm fighting with it a couple of hours and would appreciate some help.

I wrote the following simple code:

```
var assert  = require('assert'),
  webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

describe('Google Search', function() {
    var driver;

    before(function() {
        console.log("before START")

        driver = new webdriver.Builder()
        .forBrowser('firefox')
        .build();

        console.log("before END")
    });

    it('should work', function(done) {
        console.log("it START")

        driver.get('http://www.google.com/');

        console.log("it END")
    });

    after(function() {
        console.log("after START")

        driver.quit();

        console.log("after END")
    });
});
```

and run it with:

```
mocha open_google --timeout 15000
```

I would expect that firefox is opened (before block), redirected to Google (it), then closed (after).

However it does not happen. I can see that:

1. before() and it() are quickly executed (first 4 console.logs are printed practically immediatelly)
2. After a couple of seconds, Firefox is opened, but never goes to Google, it just stays there till 15 secs are elapsed.
3. The after() block is done and the browser is closed

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium-webdriver doesn't open firefox from mocha in nodejs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31685280/selenium-webdriver-doesnt-open-firefox-from-mocha-in-nodejs)

Answer (score 0):

> Dependent on several factors, including the OS/Browser combination,
>   WebDriver may or may not wait for the page to load. In some
>   circumstances, WebDriver may return control before the page has
>   finished, or even started, loading. To ensure robustness, you need to
>   wait for the element(s) to exist in the page using Explicit and
>   Implicit Waits.[1]
>
> [1]: http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp

This means, you should wait for a element to be visible to get you expected behavior. Hope this solution will work.